# Is it possible to test for an attribute specifier in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, attributes, type-traits

I'm trying to achieve different behavior based on an attribute applied to a function. Basically I'm trying to see if it is possible to test for the presence of an attribute at compile time.

```
struct AbortError
{
    [[noreturn]] static void error(const std::string& msg)
    {
        std::cerr << "critical error: " << msg << std::endl;
        std::abort();
    }
}

struct LogError
{
    static void error(const std::string& msg)
    {
        std::cerr << "non-critical error: " << msg << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to test for the presence of [[noreturn]]?

I'm hoping to acheive something like

```
template <typename ErrorPolicy>
void function()
{
    // ...
    if constexpr(std::is_noreturn<ErrorPolicy::error>::value)
    {
        performCriticalCleanup();
    }

    ErrorPolicy::error("Bad things happened.");
}
```

Comment: Attribute are not part of the signature, and C++ doesn't have reflection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *C++* does not have [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)), the answer is **no**: it is not possible.

What I, instead, suggest you to do is to make a different design choice in order to achieve the same goal.
You could use, for example, *polymorfism* in an run-time environment.

If you need some at compile time, instead, you can "integrate" a constant expression in your structure and check it later.

For example:

```
struct AbortError {
  static constexpr bool critical = true;
  // ...
};
```

or

```
struct AbortError: std::true_type {
// ...
};
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/aUo5Pa) an online example which shows both options.

Comment: Even when C++ get's reflection, it probably won't include attributes (until later, if it's decided that it's a good idea for reflection on functions to contain attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make `void error(...)` and `[[noreturn]] void error(...)` "do different things." That's a bad idea, because the difference between those two signatures is so subtle. A better approach (which has the knock-on benefit of being actually implementable in C++!) would be to use completely different function names, like this:

```
struct AbortError {
    [[noreturn]] static void fatal_error(const std::string&);
};
struct LogError {
    static void nonfatal_error(const std::string&);
};

template<class ErrorPolicy>
void function() {
    std::string msg = "Bad things happened.";
    if constexpr (requires { ErrorPolicy::fatal_error(msg); }) {
        performCriticalCleanup();
        ErrorPolicy::fatal_error(msg);
    } else {
        ErrorPolicy::nonfatal_error(msg);
    }
}
```

If you want to be "clever" about it — you shouldn't! — then a "clever" option is to use the return type itself as the communication channel. C++20 Coroutines do this with the [`std::suspend_always`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/suspend_always) and `std::suspend_never` tag types. It would look like this:

```
struct FatalTag {};
struct AbortError {
    [[noreturn]] static FatalTag error(const std::string&);
};
struct LogError {
    static void error(const std::string&);
};

template<class ErrorPolicy>
void function() {
    std::string msg = "Bad things happened.";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(ErrorPolicy::error(msg)), FatalTag>) {
        performCriticalCleanup();
    }
    ErrorPolicy::error(msg);
}
```

Since you're not using the return type for anything else in the fatal case (there *is* no return, at runtime!), it arguably makes sense to use the (now-freely-available) return type to distinguish fatal from non-fatal functions. However, personally I wouldn't; that still seems like you're overloading the same name (`ErrorPolicy::error`) to talk about two completely different behaviors, and that's confusing.

See also ["`void` versus `[[noreturn]]`"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2022/06/29/that-undiscovered-country/) (2022-06-29).